# Find marginal effects in multiple equation model with ordered probit - cmp

Tags: regression, stata, marginal-effects

I am really new to Stata, so that my question might be trivial

I am using package cmp to estimate a bivariate model that goes as follows:

```
cmp(d_ln_jobs = d_layer) (d_layer = d_tariff), vce(robust) ind($cmp_cont $cmp_probit) nolr quietly difficult
```

d_layer is an ordered variable that assumes -4, -3, ... 4.

How could I obtain the marginal effect of d_tariff on both dependent variables, evaluated at d_tariff's median?

Here is what I've tried:

```
margins, dydx(d_tariff) at((median)) force
```

I don't think this is correct since, as an output, the entry related to `dy/dx` says 0, and at the header of the output it shows:

```
"Expression: linear prediction, predict()"
```

Does this last part mean that it would show predicted probabilities rather than marginal effects? Besides, shouldn't I get a value different from 0? In my mind, `d_tariff` would change `d_layer`, which would change `d_ln_jobs`? Why don't I get two values, one showing the marginal effect on `d_layer` and the other on `d_ln_jobs`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with cmp, and I don't think much people who hang around here do. You might be better of asking this on Statalist.

Comment: @Wouter I've tried. Unfortunately nobody helped